# Laravel Homestead problem connecting to Homestead.test

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, localhost, virtualhost, homestead

I've followed the Laravel guidelines, and I have Vagrant up and running, but when I visit 'http://homestead.test/' nothing loads.

**Homestead.yaml**

```
--- ip: "192.168.10.10" memory: 2048 cpus: 1 provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/code
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

**Hosts**

```
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
#   192.168.10.10   homestead.test
```

Could anyone shed some light on what I've missed? Thanks.

**Update:** I'm now getting the following error when trying to run Homestead via GitBash:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["modifyvm", "29535830-0e33-4f82-a359-6973606f6529", "--natpf1", "delete", "ssh"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Code E_FAIL (0x80004005) - Unspecified error (extended info not available)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "LockMachine(a->session, LockType_Write)" at line 529 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp
```

Comment: What do you mean by `nothing loads`? Because a blank page would indicate it is loading something.

Comment: Hello, the page says 
"This site can’t be reached 
homestead.test’s server IP address could not be found."

Comment: Can you try ping `192.168.10.10` ?

Comment: Yes, "This site can’t be reached 192.168.10.10 took too long to respond"

Comment: I know it's sound stupid. But can you make sure the Homestead VM is running or not?

Comment: Hello, it was before but now I'm getting a new error, please see the update to the answer for details, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've accidentally commented out the `hosts` entry.

Change

```
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
#   192.168.10.10   homestead.test
```

to

```
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

192.168.10.10   homestead.test
```

Comment: Hello, I deleted the hash which was commenting it out. However although now homestead.test actually tries to establish a connection, I get the message "This site can’t be reached. Homestead.test took too long to respond." Thanks.

Comment: But that's a different error, right? Are you sure Homestead is running? `vagrant up`

Comment: Yes that's a different error.  Homestead definitely was running but now when I try to run via GitBash it gives another error which I'll add to the question now.

Comment: @Aristophanes I think it might be better to post a new question for that error, if you can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this:

```
---ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox
authorize: c:/Users/UserName/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
keys:
    - c:/Users/UserName/.ssh/id_rsa
folders:
    - map: e:/MyFolder/Homestead
      to: /home/vagrant/code
sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/public
databases:
    - homestead
```

I learned how to do it here:
https://medium.com/@eaimanshoshi/i-am-going-to-write-down-step-by-step-procedure-to-setup-homestead-for-laravel-5-2-17491a423aa

Comment: Hello, I've tried going by that guide but homestead.test still doesn't load for me, thanks.

Comment: your authorize, keys and folders map weren't configured properly

Comment: @kapitan the config file actually does allow `~` for referencing the current user's home directory (similar to unix systems), so that part is not a problem.